# KeyError when trying to access a value in Tweepy response

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter, tweepy

i'm new to parsing json files and despite trying for hours I can't find a way to do access the value I want in the json object. Here is my code:

```
# Access a tweet id and get the tweet info, then save to a txt file
tweet_id = df_tae['tweet_id'][0]
tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id, tweet_mode='extended')
with open('tweet_json_test.txt', "a") as outfile:
   json.dump(tweet._json, outfile)

# Later on, open the file and try to extract the 'media_url' address
with open('tweet_json_test.txt') as json_file:
    image = json.load(json_file)
```

I've copied an extract of "image" at the bottom of the post

Then when I call:

```
image['id']
```

I get: 892420643555336193, which is great :-)

But when I call:

```
image['media']
```

I get the following error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-849-665e447555a9> in <module>
----> 1 image['media']

KeyError: 'media'
```

How do I access the media_url string? I've tried everything I can find and think of, after hours messing around with it. I know I can get this using the tweepy API but want to be able to extract it from the json.txt later down the line.

```
# The image file looks like this (extract only for brevity):
{'created_at': 'Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017',
 'id': 892420643555336193,
 'id_str': '892420643555336193',
 'full_text': "This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in the hole of a donut. 13/10",
 'truncated': False,
 'display_text_range': [0, 85],
 'entities': {'hashtags': [],
  'symbols': [],
  'user_mentions': [],
  'urls': [],
  'media': [{'id': 892420639486877696,
    'id_str': '892420639486877696',
    'indices': [86, 109],
    'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
    'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
    'url': 'https......',
    'display_url': '.....',
    'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',
    'type': 'photo',
    'sizes': {'thumb': {'w': 150, 'h': 150, 'resize': 'crop'},
     'medium': {'w': 540, 'h': 528, 'resize': 'fit'},
     'small': {'w': 540, 'h': 528, 'resize': 'fit'},
     'large': {'w': 540, 'h': 528, 'resize': 'fit'}}}]},
```

Comment: "I've tried everything I can find and think of, after hours messing around with it." The first thing you should try, when you have a `KeyError` that you can't figure out, is to check what the `.keys()` actually are. Another thing you can do is view your JSON file in a JSON-specific viewer (any modern web browser should provide one) so that you can see the structure of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in np8's answer, I find it useful when debugging something like this to use pretty print. it's part of the standard library/modules, so not outside import/download.

simply,

```py
from pprint import pprint
# ...
pprint(mydict)
# or
pprint(mylist)
```

It usually does a good job.

### Your code

It sounds like you want to extract out all of the `media_url`s from the twitter responses.
Looking at the structure of the `image` dict, we can see...

```py
{'created_at': 'Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017',
 'display_text_range': [0, 85],
 'entities': {'hashtags': [],
              'media': [{'display_url': '.....',
                         'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',
                         'id': 892420639486877696,
                         'id_str': '892420639486877696',
                         'indices': [...],
                         'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
                         'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
                         'sizes': {...},
                         'type': 'photo',
                         'url': 'https......'}],
              'symbols': [],
              'urls': [],
              'user_mentions': []},
 'full_text': "This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in the "
              'hole of a donut. 13/10',
 'id': 892420643555336193,
 'id_str': '892420643555336193',
 'truncated': False}
```

it is a dict with an `entities` key that has a value of a dict with a `media` key that has a value of a list of dicts that has a `media_url` key. So to access those `media_url`s, we'll have to dive down through the structure to get them out.

Accessing one:

```py
first_media_url = image['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']
```

Getting all of the `media_url`s from that one tweet into a list:

```py
media_urls = [media['media_url'] for media in image['entities']['media']]
```

(Bonus) Getting all `media_url`s from all images assuming images are in a list:

```py
all_media_urls = [
    media['media_url']
    for image in images
    for media in image['entities']['media']
]
```

And remember, when working with something like tweepy, to always check the documentation, as they might layout the structure really well. Additionally, anything that has been successfully `loads`'d by the json module is now just a normal dict that you can interact with, nothing special.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its inside `entities`

```
image['entities']['media']
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get the following error

Right, because `media` isn't one of the keys of the dict loaded from the JSON; it's a key of the sub-dict under the `entities` key. So you need `image['entities']['media']`. Similarly to look into that dict and get the `media_url`: `image['entities']['media']['media_url']`.

It's *just a dict*. It doesn't matter that it came from a JSON file. The data is nested, so you access it one step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The `media` is inside another dictionary, `image['entities']`.

It might be easier to read contents of the dictionary `image` by looking at its keys:

```py
image.keys()
```

or the whole dictionary:

```py
import pprint
pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=4).pprint(image)
```

which outputs

```
{'created_at': 'Tue Aug 01 16:23:56 +0000 2017',
 'display_text_range': [0, 85],
 'entities': {'hashtags': [],
              'media': [{'display_url': '.....',
                         'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',
                         'id': 892420639486877696,
                         'id_str': '892420639486877696',
                         'indices': [...],
                         'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
                         'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DGKD1-bXoAAIAUK.jpg',
                         'sizes': {...},
                         'type': 'photo',
                         'url': 'https......'}],
              'symbols': [],
              'urls': [],
              'user_mentions': []},
 'full_text': "This is Phineas. He's a mystical boy. Only ever appears in the "
              'hole of a donut. 13/10',
 'id': 892420643555336193,
 'id_str': '892420643555336193',
 'truncated': False}
```